# Algebra problem - length of vector

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Algebra - Complex Numbers

Calculate the length of the vector given by 
$\frac{\left( 1+2i \right)\left( 1+\sqrt{3}\cdot i \right)}{\left( 1+i \right)^{3}}
$
I start by doing 
$\left( 1+i \right)^{3}=2\left( -1+i \right)$

And then I multiply both the numerator and the denominator with 
$\left( -1-i \right)$

See my [calculation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqolkmzjxfba046/2013-09-15%2014.17.52.jpg):

[image]

I can't spot where I'm going wrong in my calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can rewrite your number in its polar form:

- $1+2i=\sqrt 5e^{i\theta _1}$, for some real $\theta_1$;
- $(1+\sqrt 3i)=2e^{i\theta _2}$, for some real $\theta_2$;
- $(1+i)^3=(\sqrt 2e^{i\theta _3})^3$, for some real $\theta _3$.

Yielding $\displaystyle \left\vert\dfrac{\left( 1+2i \right)\left( 1+\sqrt{3} i \right)}{\left( 1+i \right)^{3}}\right \vert=\left \vert\dfrac{\sqrt 5e^{i\theta _1}\cdot2^{i\theta _2}}{2\sqrt 2e^{3\theta _3 i}}\right \vert=\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}.$

---

In your work you get $\dfrac{1}{2(-1+i)}=\dfrac{-1-i}{2}$ which is wrong.
 Correct is $\dfrac{1}{2(-1+i)}=\dfrac{-1-i}{4}$.

This still doesn't excuse for the absolute value of what you get being negative, but that becomes unimportant.

In any case you squared $2\sqrt 3-\sqrt 3$ wrong:
$$4\cdot 3-4\cdot 3+3=(2\sqrt 3-\sqrt 3)~2\neq 4\color{red}{\sqrt 3}-4\cdot 3+3.$$

Comment: This not only tells how it _can_ be done; it also actually answers the question where the error is. (+1)

Comment: excellent answer, thanks.

Comment: @jacob You're welcome.